# Inject service(s) into Drupal unit test?

Tags: 8, testing

I am writing a unit test upfront for a service that does not exist yet. Let's just say it is called `ResponseFormatter`.

I want to start adding unit tests for what I expect this service to do. How do I inject it to a UnitTestCase, or reference it?

Example, I am trying to do something like:

```
class FormatterTest extends UnitTestCase {

  /**
   * @dataProvider responses
   */
  public function testThisWorks($response, $expected) {
    // the following line I want to call a service, 
    // ex. like $this->responseFormatter->format($string);
    $clean = html_entity_decode(strip_tags($response));
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $clean);
  }

  public function responses() {
    return [
      ['not-set', 'not-set'],
      ['<strong>foo</strong>', 'foo'],
      ['&amp; #93 bar', '& #93 bar'],
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your new service is sufficiently independent (it doesn't have any or many of it own dependencies), then just create it the `setUp()`.  And then if you have dependencies, you set up [mocks](https://phpunit.de/manual/4.8/en/test-doubles.html) (also called doubles).

An example of a this in core is [`TimeTest::setUp()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21Tests%21Component%21Datetime%21TimeTest.php/function/TimeTest%3A%3AsetUp/8.5.x) does:

```
protected function setUp() {
  parent::setUp();

  $this->requestStack = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack')->getMock();
  $this->time = new Time($this->requestStack);
}
```

A mocked request stack is created, and the setup then directly instantiates the service class being tested ([`Time()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Datetime%21Time.php/class/Time/8.5.x) in this case), passing in the mocked dependency to the constructor.

Then assertions in test methods are pretty simple

```
public function testGetRequestTime() {
  $expected = 12345678;

  $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
  $request->server->set('REQUEST_TIME', $expected);

  // Mocks a the request stack getting the current request.
  $this->requestStack->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getCurrentRequest')
    ->willReturn($request);

  $this->assertEquals($expected, $this->time->getRequestTime());
}
```

The mock simulates what the service's dependency would do, and then the service method is invoked directly.

If your service has a lot of dependencies, or mocking them is hard, then you should do a `KernelTest` instead of a `TestCase` or `UnitTest`.  However, that may be an indication that your service is too complicated and needs to be broken up (I am also having a problem thinking of a core service that is kernel tested and not unit tested).